# Export SQLdata to excel and display multiple lines in one cell

Tags: sql, excel

[image]

I am working on a Windows Form application, and needs to export sql data to excel and to display multiple lines in one cell vertically. The sql query retrieves a series of comma separated status code, like "initiated, submitted, approved, completed", etc. When data is exported to excel file, the client would like it to be displayed vertically in a single cell, see screenshot above.
Any help and suggestions would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Excel -> Data -> Text To Column (separator - space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel representation, you will have to convert your `Status` column result into Excel formula, and use `CHAR(10)` which is a new line character for excel. So your result will look like this:

> ="Initiated" & CHAR( 10 ) & "Submitted"`

Remember, in excel for a new line to be displayed in cell, the `Wrap Text` option must be enabled.

Modify SQL query to concontenate result like below:

```
CaseID Status 
1001   ="Initiated" & CHAR( 10 ) & "Submitted"
1002   ="Approved" & CHAR( 10 ) & "Completed"
```

Comment: Thank you Amith, it works as expected. This is the sql code i used:  Select CaseID, '="' + Replace(b.Status_Code, ', ', '" & CHAR(10) & "') + '"' as [Status]
From MyTable

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.